# What's the best way to handle resizing of thumbnails for dynamic images?

Tags: mysql, apache, architecture, jboss, thumbnails

I have a web app that lets users upload images.  The images then appear as thumbnails on the app, and when a user clicks on the thumbnail it shows the full size image.  Pretty standard.

Right now I'm storing the images in a MySQL database, and have the entire app running on Jboss.  To display the thumbnails, I have an IMG html tag that points to the full size image, and I just set the width and height to 50px.  This loads the image out of the db, sends the entire thing to the client, and then resizes it in the browser.  Obviously this seems like a big waste of resources and makes the pages take a long time to load, since there could be a lot of thumbnails on the page, so I'm trying to figure out the best way to improve this.

I found an [apache module that resizes images on the fly](http://search.cpan.org/~wross/Apache-Imager-Resize-0.11/lib/Apache/Imager/Resize.pm).  So I was thinking I could use that to send the thumbnails to the client, reducing the bandwidth and page load time.  Since my images are stored in the database, is it possible and efficient for Apache to serve them?  Should I be storing the images on the file system instead?  Any suggestions on how I should handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that all the overhead of processing the request and pulling image data from the database is totally unneeded.

Just handle the resize upon upload, and serve both thumbnails and big images as static files directly via webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of images and image size - for 1 million 4MB images i would prefer not to store images in the database. But for 100 100K images yes it could handle it.

You need to consider Database backup times, and data retreival.

In one of my applications, which relied heavily on reducing database backup times and sizes, i did not store images in the database.